# How to get authentication for Using Googles Media Translation API with Springboot

Tags: spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, google-translate, google-cloud-translate

I am trying out Google's Media Translation API. I cloned their test code that can be found [here](https://github.com/googleapis/java-mediatranslation/blob/61cff2f91ecede8e709cdd3fd9d5a74e917bf8d1/samples/snippets/src/main/java/com/example/mediatranslation/TranslateFromFile.java)

but I am getting an error
`java.io.IOException: The Application Default Credentials are not available. They are available if running in Google Compute Engine. Otherwise, the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS must be defined pointing to a file defining the credentials. See https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials for more information.`

However, I already have the JSON file downloaded so I want to know how I can make the library point to that file as the source of authentication.

I have tried `export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/Users/tobilobaowolabi/Downloads/blood-drive-296909-03dad529f7b9.json` but it is not working either

Comment: Can you e.g. `more ${GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS}` to see the content of the JSON file (key)? If so, you should be doing everything correctly. The SDKs look for that variable in the environment and use it to authenticate when running off GCP. Is your code containerized or running directly in the same shell as you're exporting the variable?

Answer (score 1):

You may point your library to your source of authentication through your code.

First you need to update your **pom.xml** file and add below code inside the `<dependencies>`

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.auth</groupId>
      <artifactId>google-auth-library-oauth2-http</artifactId>
      <version>1.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Once done with **pom.xml**, go to your java code and add below code inside `translateFromFile` method.

```
String jsonPath = "<your_json_file_path>";
    GoogleCredentials credentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(new FileInputStream(jsonPath))
    .createScoped(Lists.newArrayList("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"));

 SpeechTranslationServiceSettings speechTranslationServiceSettings =
     SpeechTranslationServiceSettings.newBuilder()
         .setCredentialsProvider(FixedCredentialsProvider.create(credentials))
         .build();
```

The above code is to call your json path as credentials and then build it through `SpeechTranslationServiceSettings`.

Lastly, you need to pass [SpeechTranslationServiceSettings](https://cloud.google.com/java/docs/reference/google-cloud-mediatranslation/latest/com.google.cloud.mediatranslation.v1beta1.SpeechTranslationServiceClient) to the `create()` of [SpeechTranslationServiceClient](https://cloud.google.com/java/docs/reference/google-cloud-mediatranslation/latest/com.google.cloud.mediatranslation.v1beta1.SpeechTranslationServiceClient) .

```
try (SpeechTranslationServiceClient client = SpeechTranslationServiceClient.create(speechTranslationServiceSettings))
```

You may check this [Authentication Sample Code](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/blob/4a297200ddab741a2f34242085737fd87437f97f/auth/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/auth/samples/AuthExample.java) as reference for the authentication of credentials.